# Атрибут Draggeble элемента jQuery

Tags: jquery, php, ui

Здравствуйте! Помогите решить проблему! Есть код, который выводит картинки в цикле, у каждой свой `title`. Картинки внутри блока `div c id = "draggable"`. Эти блоки можно перетаскивать в корзину (элемент `droppable`) средствами `JQuery UI`. Подскажите, как сделать так, что бы при перетаскивании блока с картинкой на элемент `drappable` выводился `alert` с `title`'ом перетаскиваемого изображения.

Вот код:

```
<script>
 $("div#draggable").draggable();
 //Как дальше?
</script>
<?php
 echo "<div id='draggable'>";
  for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
    {
       echo "<img src='images/$i.jpg' title='$i'>";    
    }
 echo "</div>";
 echo "<div id='droppable'>Перетащите сюда</div>";
?>
```

Comment: @Макс Ковалько, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Вам необходимо ознакомится с документацией и примерами по данным компонентам. В примерах кстати есть решение которое может помочь решить вашу проблему.

- http://jqueryui.com/droppable/ -
     **доки по droppable**
- http://jqueryui.com/draggable/ -
     **доки по draggable**

Проблема которая у Вас возникла решается таким путем:
У ui компонента droppable есть обработчик события drop. Данное событие будет вызвано если вы что-то перетащите на элемент. То что вы хотите сделать можно сделать в его контексте. Пример:

```
$("div#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {            
        // Получаем элемент который перетащили и отображаем его title
        alert(ui.draggable.prop('title'));
    }
});
```

Comment: На всякий случай пример http://jsfiddle.net/Kison/FBsVE/

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Всё работает!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {            
        // Получаем элемент который перетащили и отображаем его title
        alert(ui.draggable.prop('title'));
    }
});
```

Kison прав, но код все равно не будет работать. Для "рабочести" необходимо добавить:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//javscript code
});
```

Иначе javascript при вызове метода "draggable" будет обращаться к пока не существующим элементам.